# A short programming puzzle

Tags: c++, c

What could the possible explanation for the following puzzle :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    static char *s[] = {"black","white","yellow","violet"};
    char *ptr[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s},***p;
    p = ptr;
    *++p;
    printf("%s",*--*++p + 3);
}
```

[output](http://ideone.com/qBIDo).

Comment: There is a puzzle in resolving the compiling issues here!

Comment: If anyone asked me a question like this one in an interview I'd run a mile.  Would you want to work for a company that generated code like this...?

Comment: @the_mandrill: I would love to work at such a company, but then, I tend to participate in code-golf challenges...

Answer (score 7):

```
p = ptr;
```

This is not a puzzle. It's an invalid piece of code since it assigned a `char**` to a `char***`. Actually the problem happens in the array declaration

`s+3` has type `char**`, but you declare `ptr` as an array of `char*`.

Comment: Agreed, but it comes from this contest :http://effer56.iiita.ac.in/segmentation/home.html.

Comment: t's an invalid piece of code - And thus we vote NARQ

Comment: However,I might like to add that they have set some UB question in there contest.

Comment: @Debanjan - The guys who put of this question are no coding gurus, may have copied from somewhere else !!